# VueJS Print HTML to Page

Tags: javascript, html, string, vue.js

I have a property which contains a HTML string as one of its attributes.

When I try and print this to the page within my template, it actually prints the HTML. So the text contains HTML tags, and it itself is not interpreted as HTML by the browser.

How can I fix this?

Template:

```
<div class="description">
    {{ property.description }}
</div>
```

Output:

```
<p>Suscipit est aut molestiae provident quis magnam.</p> <p>Nesciunt iure impedit sint iste.</p> <p>Aspernatur repudiandae laborum dolor harum magnam officiis ad nihil.</p> <p>Non deserunt rerum adipisci voluptates est eos et.</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***NOTE: This answer was intended for vue.js v1. For v2, please see webnoob's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41567138/4875631).***

According to the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In order to output real HTML, you will need to use triple mustaches.

Use 3 curly brackets to accomplish your task:

```
<div class="description">
    {{{ property.description }}}
</div>
```

Sidenote (Also from the docs):

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be **very dangerous** because it can easily lead to XSS attacks. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Yeah the content is inputted and validated before it enters the database, then is pulled through a Markdown parser on the backend. It's parsed and constructed before it arrives within Vue :)

Comment: This does not seem to work with vuejs 2 per the doucmentation

Comment: @noelboss The original question asked for vue.js v1 (v2 was not even out at the time). I've updated my question with a link to the post below.

Answer (score 23):

Now we're using Vue2, this has changed slightly. According to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) we need to make use of the `v-html` directive.

As an example, I've made a loading button like so:

```
<button type="submit" v-html="loading ? loadingText : 'Login'">
```

where the variables represent:

```
data: function (router) {
  return {
    loading: false,
    loadingText: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...',
  }
}
```

This would produce:

[image]

and when the `loading` state is changed to `true`

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can use v-html to do this. As said in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

```
<div class="description" v-html="property.description"></div>
```

Tripple {{{ does not work with vuejs 2.