# How to handle when VueJS computed properties return HTML code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I use `VueJS 2` to render and calculate form items. Now I need to show a number if a propertie is under 10, and I need show a text message if the propertie is over or equal 10.

I use this code:

```
Vue.component('mycomponent', {
    template: '#mytemp',
    data: function() {
        // ...
    },
    computed: {
         mycomputedprop: function() {
             if (this.model_a < 10) {
                 return '<span class="numbervalue">' + this.model_a + '€</span>';
             } else {
                 return '<span class="textvalue">I\'ll contact you as soon as possible!</span>';
             }
         }
    }
});
```

I use this code to show the value:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ mycomputedprop }}
</div>
```

The problem is: if I show this value it shows the HTML code as text, not as HTML. How can I show the returned value as a HTML code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS Print HTML to Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687645/vuejs-print-html-to-page)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could use `v-html`

Document : [Raw-HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

```
<div id="app">
 <div v-html="mycomputedprop"></div>
</div>
```

> The contents of this div will be replaced with the value of the
> rawHtml property, interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are
> ignored. Note that you cannot use v-html to compose template partials,
> because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead,
> components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and
> composition.

**Vue 3 Example:**

```js
const RenderHtmlApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      rawHtml: '<span style="color: red">This should be red.</span>'
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(RenderHtmlApp).mount('#example1')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="example1">
    <p>Using mustaches: {{ rawHtml }}</p>
    <p>Using v-html directive: <span v-html="rawHtml"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the best answer regarding the asked question. So I upvoted it. But a good practice would be to NOT return HTML. Regarding this, @JeBokE answer is "better".

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that modal_a is defined in the data of your component, why not handle this within the component template?

```
  <div id="app">
    <span v-if="model_a < 10" class="numbervalue">{{model_a}} €</span>
    <span v-else class="textvalue">I\'ll contact you as soon as possible!</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's one way to do it, but it's far from optimal. Vue discourages template handled directly into thi HTML.